# didDeselectRowAtIndexPath method not triggered after programatically selecting cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am facing a strange problem. I have a tableview with multiple selection enabled. In the cellForRowAtIndexPath method, I have the following code:

```
if getSelectionStatusForItemAt(indexPath.row)
{
    cell.selected = true
    self.tblPayments.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)
}

return cell
```

After reload data, single/multiple cells are selected. The indexPathsForSelectedCells method also returns a non empty array. But, the problem is that when I touch one of these cells again, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method is called instead of `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath`.

I think I am missing something in the way tableview delegates work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `self.tblPayments.selectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true, scrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.None)` you are selecting the row, but it remains selected until you unselect it and that's why `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called and `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` is not.

To call `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` after you select the cell you should, in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` call `tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)`. Another option is to do your operations at `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` if possible.

Comment: "it remains selected until you unselect it". From this I understand that, if the user taps the cell again, it should get unselected and hence the 'didDeselectRowAtIndexPath' method must be triggered. But that is not happening in my case

Comment: The option of doing operation in 'didSelectRowAtIndexPath' is not viable for me. I have functionality associated wth both cell selection and deselection

Comment: If the user selects it, even if it's already selected, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is called. So, I suggest that you make a check in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to see if it's already selected, and if it is, you can deselect it, if not the cell will become selected.

Comment: The cell is unselected when i check inside the didSelectRowAtIndexPath. However thanks to your suggestion I was able to solve the problem by doing another check. Marking the answer as accepted. Cheers.